# IL Linker crashes during an attempt to compile Blazor's Client side

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

#### Describe the bug

I'm unable to **run** Blazor - blazorhosted application (as a whole)

I'm unable to **compile** Blazor.Client side.

Firstly - this error occured

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB3073 The command "dotnet "C:\Admins\Admin\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\0.7.0\targets\../tools/illink/illink.dll" 
-l none --verbose --strip-security true --exclude-feature com --exclude-feature sre -v false -c link -u link -b true -d "C:\Admins\Admin\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\0.7.0\targets\../tools/mono/bcl/" -d "C:\Admins\Admin\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\0.7.0\targets\../tools
/mono/bcl/Facades/" -o "C:\Repo\Project\Blazor\Blazor.Client\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\blazor\linker/" -x 
"C:\Admins\Admin\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\0.7.0\targets\BuiltInBclLinkerDescriptor.xml" 
-x "C:\Repo\Project\Blazor\Blazor.Client\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\blazor\linker.descriptor.xml" -a 
"C:\Admins\Admin\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor\0.7.0\lib\netstandard2.0
\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.dll" -a "C:\Admins\Admin\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.browser\0.7.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Browser.dll" -a "C:\Admins\Admin\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\0.7.0\lib\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.TagHelperWorkaround.dll" -a "C:\Admins\Admin\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection\2.1.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll" -a "C:\Admins\Admin\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.abstractions\2.1.0\lib\netstandard2.0
\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll" -a "C:\Admins\Admin\.nuget\packages
\microsoft.jsinterop\0.7.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.JSInterop.dll" -a "C:\Admins\Admin\.nuget
\packages\mono.webassembly.interop\0.7.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Mono.WebAssembly.Interop.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.componentmodel.annotations\4.5.0
\lib\netstandard2.0\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll" -a "C:\Repo\Project\Blazor\Blazor.Shared
\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\Blazor.Shared.dll" -a "C:\Repo\Project\Blazor\Blazor.Shared\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.dll" -a "C:\Repo\Project\Blazor\Blazor.Client
\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\Blazor.Client.dll"" exited with code 1.   Blazor.Client   C:\Admins\Admin\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\0.7.0\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets  439
```

Then:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.dll
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.dll but was not handled in user code

System.ArgumentException: 'The directory name 'C:\Repo\Project\Blazor\Blazor.Client\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\dist\' does not exist.'
```

When trying to compile just Client side

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Blazor.Shared, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.600-preview-009426\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.RuntimeIdentifierInference.targets(143,5): message NETSDK1057: You are working with a preview version of the .NET Core SDK. You can define the SDK version via a global.json file in the current project. More at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=869452
1>Blazor.Shared -> C:\Repo\Project\Blazor\Blazor.Shared\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\Blazor.Shared.dll
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Blazor.Client, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>Blazor.Client -> C:\Repo\Project\Blazor\Blazor.Client\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\Blazor.Client.dll
2>Fatal error in IL Linker
2>Mono.Linker.LoadException: Error while processing references of 'Blazor.Client, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' ---> Mono.Linker.LoadException: Error while processing references of 'Blazor.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' ---> Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' ---> Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
2>   at Mono.Linker.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name, ReaderParameters parameters)
2>   at Mono.Linker.AssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name, ReaderParameters parameters)
2>   at Mono.Linker.LinkContext.Resolve(IMetadataScope scope)
2>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2>   at Mono.Linker.LinkContext.Resolve(IMetadataScope scope)
2>   at Mono.Linker.LinkContext.ResolveReferences(AssemblyDefinition assembly)
2>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.LoadReferencesStep.ProcessReferences(AssemblyDefinition assembly)
2>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.LoadReferencesStep.ProcessReferences(AssemblyDefinition assembly)
2>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.LoadReferencesStep.ProcessReferences(AssemblyDefinition assembly)
2>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.LoadReferencesStep.ProcessReferences(AssemblyDefinition assembly)
2>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.LoadReferencesStep.ProcessReferences(AssemblyDefinition assembly)
2>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.LoadReferencesStep.ProcessAssembly(AssemblyDefinition assembly)
2>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.BaseStep.Process(LinkContext context)
2>   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
2>   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
2>   at Mono.Linker.Driver.Run(ILogger customLogger)
2>   at Mono.Linker.Driver.Execute(String[] args, ILogger customLogger)
2>C:\Users\Admin\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\0.7.0\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets(439,5): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet "C:\Users\User\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\0.7.0\targets\../tools/illink/illink.dll" -l none --verbose --strip-security true --exclude-feature com --exclude-feature sre -v false -c link -u link -b true -d "C:\Users\User\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\0.7.0\targets\../tools/mono/bcl/" -d "C:\Users\User\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\0.7.0\targets\../tools/mono/bcl/Facades/" -o "C:\Repo\Project\Blazor\Blazor.Client\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\blazor\linker/" -x "C:\Users\User\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\0.7.0\targets\BuiltInBclLinkerDescriptor.xml" -x "C:\Repo\Project\Blazor\Blazor.Client\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\blazor\linker.descriptor.xml" -a "C:\Users\User\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor\0.7.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.dll" -a "C:\Users\User\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.browser\0.7.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Browser.dll" -a "C:\Users\User\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\0.7.0\lib\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.TagHelperWorkaround.dll" -a "C:\Users\User\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection\2.1.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll" -a "C:\Users\User\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.abstractions\2.1.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll" -a "C:\Users\User\.nuget\packages\microsoft.jsinterop\0.7.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.JSInterop.dll" -a "C:\Users\User\.nuget\packages\mono.webassembly.interop\0.7.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Mono.WebAssembly.Interop.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.componentmodel.annotations\4.5.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll" -a "C:\Repo\Project\Blazor\Blazor.Shared\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\Blazor.Shared.dll" -a "C:\Repo\Project\Blazor\Blazor.Shared\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.dll" -a "C:\Repo\Project\Blazor\Blazor.Client\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\Blazor.Client.dll"" exited with code 1.
2>Done building project "Blazor.Client.csproj" -- FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

After double clicking this error it opens:

**Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets**

in

**C:\Users\Admin.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\0.7.0\targets**

and points on this line:

```
<!--` Run the linker and put the results in /obj/<<configuration>>/<<targetframework>>/blazor/blazor/linker -->
    <Exec Command="dotnet &quot;$(MonoLinkerPath)&quot; $(_BlazorLinkerAdditionalOptions) @(_BlazorFolderLookupPaths, ' ') -o &quot;$(BlazorIntermediateLinkerOutputPath)&quot; @(_BlazorAssemblyDescriptorFiles, ' ') @(_BlazorAssembliesToLink, ' ')"  />
```

#### To Reproduce

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

Probably:

1 Install .NET 2.1.600-preview-009426

2 Install Visual Studio 2019

3 Create `dotnet new blazorhosted`

4 Try to run the app.

4. See error

#### Expected behavior

App starting properly

#### Additional

I reproduced this bug on 2 different PCs with Win7.

In both cases scenerio was literally the same.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/30 It is just a preview tool, so report issues as this announcement documented please.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug ILLink, I recommend following steps

- Compile ILLink from latest source code
- Update ILLink in the Blazor.Build package to get better debug messages.

Then you will know how type resolution fails.
Also if you hit these kind of errors, very likely you are using reflection, or other way for dynamic types resolution which break ILLink. You should start [manually opt-out specific types from elimination by ILLink](https://blazor.net/docs/host-and-deploy/configure-linker.html).